# Issue on Updating Custom Attribute Data of Popover Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add dynamically text into Bootstrap 3 Popover `data-content=""` at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/52VtD/8938/). Basically what I want to do is updating the `data-content=""` text buy clicking different buttons. I tried to do this by adding:

```
 $("#poper").('[data-content="City"]');
```

but this is not doing the job! Here is the jquery I have

```
  $("#show-content-one").click(function(){
      $("#poper").popover('show');
      $("#poper").('[data-content="City"]');
        $("#poper").popover('show');
    });

  $("#show-content-two").click(function(){
        $("#poper").('[data-content="Country"]');
        $("#poper").popover('show');
    });
```

and HTML is:

```
<a href="#"  class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="poper" data-toggle="popover" data-content="">Dynamic Content Popover</a>

    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="show-content-one" value="content One" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="show-content-two" value="content Two" />
```

Can you please help me to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a custom attribute use the method [data().](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$("#poper").data('content', 'city');
```

What you've written is a selector, not an updater.